# How to implement loadstate with adapter, recyclerView?

Tags: android

I would like to implement a feature like loadStateFlow in Paging 3.
I do not use pagination in my implementation and it is not necessary in my case.
Could I make it another way?
I have found something like LoadingStateAdapter library
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/LoadStateAdapter

For now I get a list using method in the fragment:

```
    private fun collectNotificationItems() {
        vm.notificationData.collectWith(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            notificationAdapter.items = it
    }
}
```

This is implementation I would like to achieve, example is in paging3:

```
    private fun collectItems() {
        vm.items.collectWith(viewLifecycleOwner, adapter::submitData)
        adapter.loadStateFlow.collectWith(viewLifecycleOwner) { loadState ->
            vm.setLoadingState(loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading)
            val isEmpty =
                loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading && loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached && archiveAdapter.itemCount < 1
            vm.setEmptyStateVisible(isEmpty)
        }
    }
```

Where methods are:
in ViewModel

```
    fun setLoadingState(isLoading: Boolean) {
        _areShimmersVisible.value = isLoading && !_isSwipingToRefresh.value
        if (!isLoading) _isSwipingToRefresh.value = false
    }
```

areShimmers and isSwiping are MutableStateFlow

Could you recommend any other options?

EDIT:

I have the whole implementation a little bit different.
I have use case to make it

```
class GetListItemDetailsUseCase @Inject constructor(private val dao: Dao): BaseFlowUseCase<Unit, List<ItemData>>() {
    override fun create(params: Unit): Flow<List<ItemData>> {
        return flow{
            emit(dao.readAllData())
        }
    }
}
```

For now it looks like the code above.
How to use DateState in that case?

EDIT2:

```
class GetNotificationListItemDetailsUseCase @Inject constructor(private val notificationDao: NotificationDao): BaseFlowUseCase<Unit, DataState<List<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>>>() {
    override fun create(params: Unit): Flow<DataState<List<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>>> {
        return flow{
            emit(DataState.Loading)

            try {
                emit(DataState.Success(notificationDao.readAllDataState()))
            } catch(e: Exception) {
                emit(DataState.Error(e)) // error, and send the exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DAO

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM notification_list ORDER BY id ASC")
    abstract suspend fun readAllDataState(): DataState<List<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>>
```

/\ error beacause of it:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
```

fragment

```
    private suspend fun collectNotificationItems() {
        vm.notificationData.collectLatest { dataState ->
            when(dataState) {
                is DataState.Error -> {
                    collectErrorState()
                    Log.d("collectNotificationItems", "Collect ErrorState")
                }
                DataState.Loading -> {
                    Log.d("collectNotificationItems", "Collect Loading")
                }
                is DataState.Success<*> -> {
                    vm.notificationData.collectWith(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                        notificationAdapter.items = it
                        notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        Log.d("collectNotificationItems", "Collect Sucess")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a utility class (usually called `DataState` or something like that).

```
sealed class DataState<out T> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : DataState<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : DataState<Nothing>()
    object Loading : DataState<Nothing>()
}
```

Then, you change your flow's return type from `Flow<YourObject>` to `Flow<DataState<YourObject>>` and emit the DataStates within a `flow {}` or `channelFlow {}` block.

```
val notificationsFlow: Flow<DataState<YourObject>> get() = flow {
  emit(DataState.Loading) // when you collect, you will receive this DataState telling you that it's loading
  try {
    // networking/database stuff
    emit(DataState.Success(yourResultObject))
  } catch(e: Exception) {
    emit(DataState.Error(e)) // error, and send the exception
  }
}
```

Finally, just change your `collect {}` to be like:

```
notificationsFlow.collectLatest { dataState ->
  when(dataState) {
    is DataState.Error -> { } // error occurred, deal with it here
    DataState.Loading -> {  } // it's loading, show progress bar or something
    is DataState.Success -> {  } // data received from the flow, access it with dataState.data
  }
}
```

For more information on this regard, check [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#addendum) out.

Comment: I have edited my post. How should I implement DateState in my case?
I cannot just add <DateState> there.

Comment: @chrisu.chrisu thanks for editing! That made things clearer. First, in your UseCase, why are you returning a flow if there's only one emission? Make the DAO return a flow or don't make the UseCase return a flow at all, I think that would be better. If you wanted to fit a DataState in there, you'd have to change create's return type in BaseFlowUseCase from Flow<T> to Flow<DataState<T>>, if that's possible. If you are not able to change the interface, try changing from BaseFlowUseCase<Unit, List<ItemData>>() to BaseFlowUseCase<Unit, DataState<List<ItemData>>>().

Comment: I have done everything, but there is a compiler issue.
* I also tried suspend fun with DAO
My DAO:
    @Query("SELECT * FROM notification_list ORDER BY id ASC")
    abstract fun readAllDataState(): DataState<List<ItemData>>, I edited main post

Comment: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type

Comment: I have made another post for this issue. Thank you for Help Dannly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183608/not-sure-how-to-convert-a-cursor-to-this-methods-return-type-with-dao